# How do I print a list using modulus?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a list of possible numbers that produce a modulus from a list if possible.

```
def transaction(reg_total, total_cost, currency_paid):
    credit = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01]
    change_due = currency_paid - total_cost
    new_reg_total = reg_total - change_due
    for unit in credit:
        if change_due % unit != 0:
            change_list = []
            change_list.append(unit)
    return new_reg_total, change_due, change_list

first_trans = transaction(200, 24.52, 30)
print(first_trans)
```

I want:

```
5
.25
.10
.10
.01
.01
.01
```

Comment: In what way does your code fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: (I empathize with you frustration; learning programming can take a lot of effort. But that stuff isn't relevant when asking questions here. Please try to focus on your question, not on background information.)

Comment: Perhaps: change_list = [] should be moved to just before the for loop.

Comment: I either get the same result back from `return change_due, change_list` or `change_list` reproduces `currency_list`. It is not returning the remaining value of each possible `unit`, which would result in the bottom portion of my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly you can generate a list of numbers that produce a non-zero modulus using a list comprehension.

```py
a = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01]
b = 5.48
mod = [x for x in a if b % x != 0]
```

However, from your code snippet it seems as if modulus is not what you are looking for. If you are looking to calculate the change that would be needed you might what something more like the below:

```py
def change(due):
    credit = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01]

    for unit in credit:
        if due - unit >= 0:
            return [unit] + change(due - unit)

    return []
```